new mainboard, wifi doesn't show up, how do you install appropriate drivers?
Background
I've just rebuilt my system with a new *mainboard and processor.
All of the hardware has been identified (and associated drivers have been installed) except the wifi hardware.  Meaning, I don't see any wifi in my settings.
I only see Network & Bluetooth (no wifi):

*You can see more details about the board here.
NOTE - Ethernet / wired connection has no problems at all.
What I've Tried
Ran the command:
$ lspci -nn | grep -i network
That displayed the following:

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8852CE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller [10ec:c852] (rev
01)

How would I install a driver to get the hardware to show up in Settings (in my OS)?

Starting point is knowing what Ubuntu product & release you're using; if you need a newer kernel stack there are command(s) do to that, but we don't yet know what you're actually running.
